# Zurb Foundation - What version?

Tags: zurb-foundation, version

I've been using a free Zurb Foundation template but struggle to add any new features.

My question is this, how do I see what version of Foundation I'm using?

Answer (score 2):

The latest version of Foundation 5 I just downloaded has the version number in the css/foundation.css file at the top:

```
meta.foundation-version {font-family: "/5.5.2/";}
```

also in js/foundation.min.css (search in the file for "version"):

```
version : '5.5.2'
```